# How to execute command lines as root in a Hudson job?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hudson, root, slave

In Hudson, I created a job that try to execute this command line in an Ubuntu Hudson Slave :

```
sudo mount -t cifs //path/to/network/directory /path/to/local/directory -o username=<Account>,password=<AccountPassword>,domain=<DomaineName>
```

But I get this **error** :

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Then, I try to execute this command line in the Hudson job instead :

```
mount -t cifs //path/to/network/directory /path/to/local/directory -o username=<Account>,password=<AccountPassword>,domain=<DomaineName>
```

Then, I get this **error** :

```
mount: only root can do that
```

Then I tried this command line (I tried it because this command work in putty):

```
ssh "sudo mount -t cifs //path/to/network/directory /path/to/local/directory -o username=<Account>,password=<AccountPassword>,domain=<DomaineName>"
```

But I failed by this **error** :

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ,domain=<DomaineName>: Name or service not known
```

After reading [this](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/samba-only-root-can-do-that/start) I tried to resolve the previous error by executing this command line in the Ubuntu terminal :

```
sudo chmod a+s /sbin/mount.cifs
```

But this didn't resolve my problem.

This didn't work either :

```
mount.cifs //path/to/network/directory /path/to/local/directory -o username=<Account>,password=<AccountPassword>,domain=<DomaineName>
```

Should I get the way to **authenticate as root in the Hudson job** (password should be set at an automatic way)? Or should I give root privileges to Hudson user?

How can I resolve this problem?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: This question is not about "general computing hardware and software", also it's not about administration.. I'm a developer, and these days i'm scripting by shell, more specifically the scripts i do are injected in Hudson builds. So, maybe my command line has something wrong. Thank you for reviewing my question and re-opening it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing to do is probably add the mount to /etc/fstab and specify the "user" option, so you don't have to be root to do the mount.

The line you add to /etc/fstab should look like this:

```
//path/to/network/directory /path/to/local/directory cifs noauto,user,username=<account>,password=<password>,domain=<domain> 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I'm not right to add the password in fstab file. It must be filled at Hudson Job level. Thanks

Comment: Maybe it would work if you put everything but the password into fstab, and gave the password on the command line. But you'd have to try that out, i can't where i am atm.